Can I harvest and prune at the same time?
my peach tree is only five years old and its production is massive causing the tree to tip over!  I would like to prune it as I harvest it, accomplishing two birds with one stone. is that okay?
I keep hearing I shouldn't prune my trees till dormant season. That would be late Oct early November here in Cal. They say if I prune too early my trees will go into shock

You can do, but I see two problems, so you should check and balance the advantages and disadvantages.
Often in peach we must prune a lot, really a lot: 50% to 70% of branches, or also more. Peach will not forgive (and forget) pruning errors: if the tree go too high, it is nearly impossible to get lower branches.
But so pruning is removing a lot of branches and leaves, which they may be needed until wintering: before wintering (after fruiting) the extra energy is used to prepare energy for next season (wild instinct: growth faster and taller then other plants). Part of energy is stored temporarily in branches and leaves, and after fall of leaves, most of the starch will be stored in root.
The second problem is about your overproduction. Peach (and most fruit plants) tend to do alternate growth: one year a lot of fruits, the other year a lot of branches, and repeating the cycle. So now you are in the fruit year, so a lot of energy went to fruit and not to the tree. Note: pruning is our human way to reduce the two year cycle: balanced yield, but every year.
So, combining both (yearly pruning and branch-year), you may get zero yield next year. So I would be careful. you may start to reduce the number of peaches (remove the worst one). In reality you should have removed excess fruits months ago (the rule of fists: one fists between each fruit): as you see: branches are not strong as in other fruit plants.
You may uses some emergency measure, like sticks, canes, ropes, to help branches not to break from weight.

Pruning at the wrong time means removing upcoming flowers, then fruit. Pruning at harvest eliminates that risk.
Many feel you can also prune year-round for symmetry/aesthetics, convenience, or danger. Opinions differ.
There's also an old saw Prune when the knife is sharp, meaning at a time best for you. There is the chance that buds are forming months before they're seen, so you are harming them. But nature compensates with fewer, bigger flowers and harvest.
